# Using local env to test sanity IO

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

The error is:

```
Uncaught error: Can't find variable: process
http://localhost:3333/sanity.config.ts:5:26
```

It is with the .env.local file. I found this by entering my project ID directly into the sanity config file. However, I am trying to figure why my .env.local file will not work. I have noticed from watching a tutorial my .env file does not have the little gear icon that other people had. Why is that?

here is my .en.local file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID= xxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET= production
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_VERSION=2022-11-15
```

[see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrjGw.png)

here is the sanity.config.ts file pulling using env.local file:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'sanity'
import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk'
import {visionTool} from '@sanity/vision'
import {schemaTypes} from './schemas'

const projectId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID!
const dataset = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET!


export default defineConfig({
   name: 'Jeremy',
   title: 'Sanity Stuff',

  projectId,
  dataset,

  plugins: [deskTool(), visionTool()],

  schema: {
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
 })
```

tsconfig.json:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
   "allowJs": true,
   "skipLibCheck": true,
   "strict": true,
   "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
   "noEmit": true,
   "esModuleInterop": true,
   "module": "esnext",
   "moduleResolution": "node",
   "resolveJsonModule": true,
   "isolatedModules": true,
   "jsx": "preserve",
   "incremental": true,
   "baseUrl": ".",
   "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
   }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

package.json in sanity project folder:

```
  {
   "name": "sanity-stuff",
   "private": true,
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "main": "package.json",
   "license": "UNLICENSED",
   "scripts": {
     "dev": "sanity dev",
     "start": "sanity start",
    "build": "sanity build",
    "deploy": "sanity deploy",
    "deploy-graphql": "sanity graphql deploy"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sanity"
  ],
   "dependencies": {
    "@portabletext/react": "^2.0.1",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.2",
    "@sanity/vision": "^3.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "envdot": "^0.0.3",
    "next": "^13.1.6",
    "next-sanity": "^4.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-is": "^18.2.0",
    "sanity": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   "@sanity/eslint-config-studio": "^2.0.1",
   "eslint": "^8.6.0",
   "prettier": "^2.8.4",
   "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  },
 "prettier": {
 "semi": false,
 "printWidth": 100,
 "bracketSpacing": false,
 "singleQuote": true
  }
 }
```

Comment: To help you, we need to see more code. Can you show an example of where you are retrieving the values in your code? Also, you should only ask one question per post, otherwise your question might get closed.

Comment: @gunwin I added some more

Comment: One more, can you share the contents of your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: gunwin
added tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1):

Sanity Studio has [their own convention](https://www.sanity.io/docs/studio-environment-variables) for environment variables.

> You can also add your own variables to the Studio environment with the **SANITY_STUDIO_ prefix**, and you can use so-called “dot env” (.env) files to more easily manage environment variables when developing locally.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I am still getting a the same error.

Comment: Are you using Vite or React-scripts?

Comment: no to react-scripts but yes to vite:  sanity@3.3.1
  ├─┬ @vitejs/plugin-react@3.1.0
  │ └── vite@4.1.1 deduped
  └── vite@4.1.1

Comment: In `Vite`, you must use `import.meta` not `process`.

Comment: would I still need an .env.local file for that?

Comment: The environment files still work the same for the most part --- just use `VITE_` to prefix your variables.

Comment: like this?    import {defineConfig} from 'sanity'
import {visionTool} from '@sanity/vision';
import {deskTool} from 'sanity/desk'
import {schemaTypes} from './schemas';

const projectId = import.meta.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID;
const dataset = import.meta.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET;

export default defineConfig({
  name: 'Jeremy',
  title: 'Sanity Stuff',

  projectId,
  dataset,

  plugins: [deskTool(), visionTool()],

  schema: {
    types: schemaTypes,
  },
});

Comment: My apologies, for your case, you want to use `SANITY_STUDIO_` prefix for environment variables since you're using Sanity Studio. So not `VITE_` and not `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Comment: I tried these but it still did not work. If it helps whenever I launch the server i get this message: "Sanity Studio using vite@4.1.1 ready in 4284ms and running at http://localhost:3333/". Also, my .env file, sanity config and CLI file are in my sanity project which in my larger project.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your app structure particularly the package.json?

Comment: I have a main project folder which includes a NEXT folder, a components folder and a few other folders that operate the front end. Within my main folder I also have the Sanity project folder which has it's own separate package.json which I will add to the main post.